# TelegramAPI. Проверка ввода пользовательских данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Друзья,добрый день. Возникла проблема с осуществлением проверки пользовательских данных при такой реализации (см код) по какой-то причине цикл не прерывается и постоянно просит ввести корректные данные. Вот код

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['btc'])


def btc(message):
    print('BTC')
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введите число для конвертирования биткойнов')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send,value)


def value(message):
    print("step")
    count = message.text
    while True:
        try: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Cумма в долларах будет составлять {count} $'.format(
            count=float(count) * float(get_btc()['usd'])))
        except:
            print('IN')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Необходимо ввести именно число')




def main():
    bot.polling()

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Цикл необходимо прервать с помощю `finnaly: break`.

```
def value(message):
        print("step")
        count = message.text
        while True:
            try: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Cумма в долларах будет составлять {count} $'.format(count=float(count) * float(get_btc()['usd'])))
            except:
                print('IN')
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Необходимо ввести именно число')
            finally:
                break
```